# Can modular exponentiation with a public index be considered a secure permutation?

Tags: public-key, modular-arithmetic, permutation

Secure permutation can be used in Sponge and Duplex constructions to build hash functions and encryption. To potentially use them in public-key cryptography, some arithmetic properties is desired.

Can modular exponentiation with a public index be considered a secure permutation? What public attacks are available? Are there constructions proven to be insecure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can modular exponentiation with a public index be considered a secure permutation?

I'll assume the permutation thought is $f_{(n,e)}:\ x\mapsto x^e\bmod n$ with odd $n>2$, odd $e>1$, and $x$ in the set $\{0,1,\ldots n-2,n-1\}$ less some subset of $\{0,1,n-1\}$.

$f_{(n,e)}$ is a permutation when $n$ is [square-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer), and $e$ is coprime with $\varphi(n)$.

When $n$ has $k$ (distinct) prime factors, $f$ has $3^k$ stationary points: any $x$ with $x\bmod p\in\{0,1,p-1\}$ for every prime $p$ dividing $n$. That always include $0$, $1$, and $n-1$, which is why we may want to remove them.

If $2^i+3$ is prime (that is for $i$ in [A057732](https://oeis.org/A057732)), and $e$ is coprime with $2^i+2$, then $g_{(i,e)}:\ x\mapsto((x+2)^e-2)\bmod(2^i+3)$ is a permutation of $[0,2^i)$ (which easily maps to the set of $i$-bit bitstrings), with the three obvious fixed points removed. We probably also want $e>i$, and may want $e$ of low Hamming weight. Examples where that construction might be useful: $(i,e)=(30,65)$, or $(i,e)=(784,1025)$. The later is a 98-byte permutation that's reasonably fast to evaluate. There is good hardware support in some crypto environments.

The permutation is easily invertible when the factorization of $n$ is public: we do as in RSA, that's at worse about $\log_2(n)/\log_2(e)$ more costly than the direct permutation.

Is that secure? It depends on the usage. It holds $f_{(n,e)}(x)f_{(n,e)}(y)\bmod n=f_{(n,e)}(x\,y\bmod n)$, which makes that permutation $f_{(n,e)}$ very special, and there's analog property for $g_{(i,e)}$. Thus we do not have a good substitute for a random permutation in all use cases of these, but that might do when combined with XOR for a few rounds in some symmetric crypto primitive.